# Random Numb to display random link

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random, floor

I am making a page that shows a random link on it. In the JavaScript code, it includes an array of links and if the user does not have Java enabled, it automatically sets the link to YouTube. This is just an exercise that I got assigned, just letting you know. Currently, no link shows up.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Working with Randoms</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="random.js"></script>
<h1>Random Link</h1>
<div id="random_link"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var jsEnabled = navigator.javaEnabled();
var rand_link = document.getElementById("random_link");

if(jsEnabled=false;){
rand_link.innerHTML = "<a href="www.youtube.com">Default Link</a>";}

var link = new Array(5);
link[0]="http://www.pageresource.com";
link[1]="http://www.javascriptcity.com;"
link[2]="http://www.mydemos.com";
link[3]="http://www.yahoo.com";
link[4]="http://www.google.com";

var rand_int = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);

rand_link.innerHTML = "<a href="+link[rand_int]+">Random Link!</a>"
```

Comment: Please have a look at the console of your browser.

Comment: I think last time I saw `navigator.javaEnabled` was 1999.

Comment: Why do you do an assignment in `if` condition?

Answer (score 0):

Typo.

Replace:

```
link[1]="http://www.javascriptcity.com;"
```

With:

```
link[1]="http://www.javascriptcity.com";
//                                    ^
```

And replace:

```
if(jsEnabled=false;){
```

With:

```
if(jsEnabled == false){
//           ^ `==` means "equals", A single `=` is an assignment.
// Also, no `;` in `if` statements.
```

And finally:

```
rand_link.innerHTML = "<a href="www.youtube.com">Default Link</a>";}
```

With:

```
rand_link.innerHTML = "<a href=\"www.youtube.com\">Default Link</a>";}
//                             ^ Escape quotes in a string
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another solution

```
var jsEnabled = navigator.javaEnabled();
var rand_link = document.getElementById("random_link");

// You had a Typo in the if sytaxt
if(jsEnabled==false){
    rand_link.innerHTML = '<a href="www.youtube.com">Default Link</a>';
}

var link = new Array();
link[0]="http://www.pageresource.com";
link[1]="http://www.javascriptcity.com;"
link[2]="http://www.mydemos.com";
link[3]="http://www.yahoo.com";
link[4]="http://www.google.com";

// The math.random returns a value form 0 to 1. The returned value is a float, 
// and you need a int to access an element in an array. You need to add modulo 
// 5 to the solution. Wich gives you a value between 0 to 4 
var rand_int = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)%5;

rand_link.innerHTML = "<a href="+link[rand_int]+">Random Link!</a>"
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gvLLuv8y/